# Conceptual question about React.js Components Structure

Tags: reactjs

> At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t
> found any use cases where we would recommend creating component
> inheritance hierarchies. [Source @reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance)

I use react, and I use most of the tools. But I get lost here, what exactly do they mean by Inheritance hierarchies?

Answer (score 0):

It means there is no necessary case to `extend` a React class component from another component.

Instead, they advice to use composition to build UI components.

Comment: But they use `extends` in almost every example on the site XD...

Comment: I mean they extend the React Component class or Pure component. but when you have created the class of your own ..there is no need to keep on extending that class to reuse the methods and stuff.